# CSS animation Flip Clock

Tags: html, css

i have a problem when making **Flip Clock** animation

the animation will perform like this reference

**reference** : http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

so far, this is my work.

**demo** : https://jsfiddle.net/s3qk25m7/1

i try this one :

**HTML** :

```
<div class="time">
  <span class="count top flipTop">2</span>
    <span class="count top">1</span>
    <span class="count bottom flipBottom">1</span>
  <span class="count bottom">2</span>
</div>
```

**CSS** :

```
.time {position: relative; height: 95px; width: 65px;
  perspective: 200px; backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0); transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.count {background: #202020; color: #f8f8f8; display: block;
  font-size: 2em; line-height: 2.4em; overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute; text-align: center;
  top: 0; width: 100%;
}
.top {height: 50%; line-height:95px; transform-origin: 50% 100%; }
.bottom {line-height: 0; height: 50%; top: 50%; transform-origin: 50% 0; }

@keyframes flipTop {
  from {
      transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  to {
      transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  }
}
@keyframes flipBottom {
    from {
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
}

.flipTop {
    animation-name: flipTop;
    animation-duration: 0.25s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.flipBottom {
    animation-name: flipBottom;
    animation-duration: 0.25s;
     animation-delay: 0.25s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

the animation not working properly. how to solve this issue?

what's wrong with my code?

thanks in advance...

Comment: What's the problem with the animation?

Comment: thanks Aides for commenting, it's just doesn't work like this http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/ when it comes to flip. the number not really rotating.

Comment: Just added a reference to some other interesting source you might be interested in. See **Edit 2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the animated div is behind the static.

To fix this add `z-index: 1` to your `.flipPosition` class.

Check out [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/00ke0269/2/)

**Edit:** note that the lower div's number seems to be updated too early

**Edit 2:** I just realized that [ngAnimateSwap](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/docs/api/ngAnimate/directive/ngAnimateSwap) would probably be perfect for this!